# how to transition between 2 skscenes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, transition, scene

I've been trying for the LONGEST time to transition between my 2 skscenes. With the new swifts, nothing has worked. I've tried using the transition in the gameviewcontroller already there

```
if let view = self.view {
   // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
   if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "NextLevelTab") {
      // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
      scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

      // Present the scene
      view.presentScene(scene)
   }
   view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true                 
   view.showsFPS = true
   view.showsNodeCount = true
 }
```

and tried to use another method i found online

```
let reveal = SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 1)
let MainMenuTab = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
scene?.view?.presentScene(MainMenuTab,transition: reveal)
```

but nothing's worked. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: "nothing's worked", do you mean that the second scene is not presented or?

Comment: is your GameScene constructed in the Scene Editor (is there a GameScene.sks file) or is constructed entirely in code?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, it doesn’t present.

Comment: @RonMyschuk Yes there’s an sks file

Answer (score 0):

the code below is for when you are presenting a scene using the init() function and there is not a SKS corresponding file

```
let reveal = SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 1)
let MainMenuTab = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
scene?.view?.presentScene(MainMenuTab,transition: reveal)
```

When you have an SKS file use the following where the first GameScene is the class name and the GameScene in quotes is the name of the sks files

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") { }
```

Comment: So if im getting at this right, the first code piece is for presenting one scene, and the second line is for transitioning from one scene to another?

Comment: same thing, one just loads the scene from the sks file and the other loads it from code